# IIS 7.5 web site directory permisions

Tags: iis-7.5

As a learning experience I'm setting up (and trying to harden) a Windows 2008R2 web server.

My web sites are stored on a separate partition and are organized as below:

```
/domains
    /somedomain.com
        /logs
        /wwwroot
    /anotherdomain.com
        /logs
        /wwwroot
```

I've removed the default permissions for the "Users" group from the "domains" directory.

Here are the permissions for /domains

```
D:\Domains NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F 
           BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)F 
           CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
```

Each web site is configured with a separate application pool running under AppPoolIdentity.

I've granted modify rights to the "wwwroot" for the appropriate application pool user and read permissions for the anonymous user:

```
D:\domains\somedomain.com\wwwroot IIS APPPOOL\somedomain.com:(OI)(CI)C 
                                    NT AUTHORITY\IUSR:(OI)(CI)R 
                                    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(ID)F 
                                    BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(ID)F 
                                    CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(ID)F
```

Is there anything else that I am missing regarding the directory permissions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar, but still differently:

1. Why do you need Modify rights granted to `wwwroot` folder? Read & Execute is enough and only grant Modify when required (e.g. `temp`, `upload`, `cache` folders -- where content will be created/changed, for example by website app (PHP/ASP.NET etc)).

   I grant "Read & Execute" to `D:\domains\somedomain.com` (it is enough) and Modify to a specific folders: `D:\domains\somedomain.com\var`. If I have an app/script that requires Modify right on web-accessible folder (for example, LiveZilla live chat software), then I grant it there, e.g. `D:\domains\somedomain.com\wwwroot\livechat\banners`.
2. I do not use IUSR user -- I'm using "Application pool identity" instead:

   - "Application user (pass-trough authentication)" on *"Site | Basic Settings | Connect as"*
   - and "Application pool identity" on *"Site | Authentication | Anonymous Authentication"*
3. I do not have "CREATOR OWNER" at all (it was causing problems when running PHP scripts -- unable to execute them at all + something else (don't remember now), so I have removed it from the whole `D:\domains`). I pretty much have: SYSTEM, Admins, APP_POOL_SPECIFIC_ID, SPECIFIC_FTP_USER.

The above works fine for me on 6 servers with no issues so far (Am I lucky?).

Comment: 1. The application requires write access, but you're right I should really just allow right access to specific directories. 2. I prefer to keep the identity of my application pool (that the web site runs under) and that of my web site visitors separate.